# C compiler expecting additional argument in function despite not being declared

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am declaring a function with 2 arguments and calling it with 2 arguments however the compiler seems to be converting it into a function that requires an additional argument of type `FILE * __restrict`.

I'm on Mac OSX 10.11.6
using both `cc` and `gcc` produces the same error.

What argument should I be giving the function or should I be changing a setting with my compiler? Or have I just missed a typo somewhere...

Errors are:

```
longest-line.c:6:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(char line[], int maxline);
    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:442:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict, FILE * __restrict) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
        ^
longest-line.c:17:37: error: too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2
        while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
                      ~~~~~~~              ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:442:1: note: 'getline' declared here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict, FILE * __restrict) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
^
longest-line.c:28:5: error: conflicting types for 'getline'
int getline(char s[], int lim)
    ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:442:9: note: previous declaration is here
ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict, size_t * __restrict, FILE * __restrict) __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_4_3);
        ^
3 errors generated.
```

Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

int main()
{
    int len;                /* current line length */
    int max;                /* maximum length so far */
    char line[MAXLINE];     /* current input line */
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /* longest line saved here */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)  /* there was a line */
        printf("%s", longest);

    return 0;
}

int getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i<lim-1 && (c=getchar()) != 'X' && c!='\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: [`getline` is already a thing.](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)

Comment: For future reference, the error message “/usr/include/stdio.h:442:9: note: previous declaration is here” tells you that a previous declaration is at line 442 of the file /usr/include/stdio.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getline` is a name reserved (in POSIX), you can't use it without trouble, change your function name.

Comment: It's not reserved by the C standard. It's defined by POSIX.

Comment: Thanks very much will keep an eye out for reserved names in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`getline` is defined in `stdio.h`. When you're declaring it, another declaration has already been provided and your version isn't being picked up.

As Stargateur has already pointed out, it's reserved -- change your function name.